# Where can I buy or download the soundtrack for Fairy Tail?

Tags: music, fairy-tail, merchandise, united-states

I would like to purchase/download the Fairy Tail OST, but I don't know where/how. Not the physical disc(s), but the digital file(s). Sources, online stores, instructions, etc.?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Which sites have you looked at and didn't find what you were looking for? It would help with the search if you listed them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy it from sites such as [Recochoku](https://recochoku.jp/song/S1003350690/). As for payment method you can choose Webmoney and buy the Japan Webmoney prepaid code from another site (just google for it - there are quite many choices). It's a roundabout way but probably cheaper than buying it imported at wherever you're living in. Oh, and being able to read Japanese is a must, since most of these sites don't have English translations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your location. In the U.S. you can find the OSTs on iTunes. However, the Japanese music industry is not very fond of letting their music out of the country, at least in digital format. I have recently discovered that they finally decided to put the first couple Fairy Tail OSTs on the U.S. iTunes store, years after their release in Japan. Given that iTunes is arguably the most widely used platform for digital distribution of music, and that it took that long for the OSTs to arrive in the U.S. store, it might not even be available for digital purchase in your country at the moment.